# How to decrypt in PHP without mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have implemented next function to decrypt string using mcrypt:

```
function decrypt($encrypted){

    $key = "I5G9VjmnDQ483iDwE9278ST01Rp12Mr7";
    $iv = "W3gtod2XaqHRgdo57968xys2738tl2S6";

    $iv_utf = mb_convert_encoding($iv, 'UTF-8');

    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_utf);

    return $decrypted;

}
```

Is there any alternative to this without using `mcrypt`. I don't want to depends on this extension anymore.

I found good library on Github [here](https://github.com/gilfether/phpcrypt) but it requires PHP v5.3 or later. I need something what works with PHP v5.2.4 or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`

Sorry, no sane library supports Rijndael256. They support standard AES, however. (If anyone is reading this and you want secure and reliably cryptography in 2015, **[stop using mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)!**)

> Is there any alternative to this without using `mcrypt`. I don't want to depends on this extension anymore.

Not with Rijndael256. I highly recommend [this secure PHP encryption library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), which implements authenticated encryption using industry standard AES, supplied by PHP's OpenSSL extension.

> I found good library on Github [here](https://github.com/gilfether/phpcrypt).

For a given definition of "good".

- This library comes with a pure-PHP implementation of Rijndael. It's never a good idea to write your own implementations of a cipher, especially in a language like PHP.
- The code also makes liberal use of `substr()` and `strlen()`, without any sanity checks for `mbstring.func_overload`.
- It fails to offer [authenticated encryption](http://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken), which is what you want in 99.9% of cases.

> but it requires PHP v5.3 or later. I need something what works with PHP v5.2.4 or later

Read [this](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/on-php-version-requirements.html) and PLEASE upgrade to 5.6. The 5.2, 5.3, and 5.4 branches are no longer receiving security updates, so you'll have bigger problems than merely insecure cryptography.